# Redirected Page has Some Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

i have one asp.net project. In this i used session for logged user. If i open a popup window and waited upto session expire. Then i got one error page that describing about the session expiration and redirect to the login page. but the login page open in the same popup window. My requirement is to open the login page in Main window. What changes that i will make for that?

```
if (Session["IsSessionValid"] != null)
{
   //Some lines of codes
}
else
{
  Response.Redirect("SessionError.aspx");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know i think we can use javascript to load the parent window with a new url

Write a function for the popup window.onclose event

In that function, you can refer the parent window from which you have opened a popup,

```
window.opener.location=url //replace the url of ur wish
```